# How to make a gap or margin bottom to labels?

Tags: javascript, gauge

I am using [gauge.js](http://bernii.github.io/gauge.js/) library. 
I want to make a gap or margin bottom to labels. Any help will be really appreciated . Thanks

[image]

```
selectGauge3 = new Gauge(document.getElementById("canvas-preview"));
var opts = {
angle: 0.05,
  radiusScale: 0.8, // Relative radius
lineWidth: 0.05,
pointer: {
//Extra optional pointer options:
  iconPath: 'http://localhost/gauge/gauge.js-gh-pages/yellow1.png',  // Icon image source
  iconScale: 0.90,    // Size scaling factor
  iconAngle: 100.0,  // Rotation offset angle, degrees
  strokeWidth: 0,
  length: 0.5,
 },
 staticLabels: {
    font: "18px sans-serif",  // Specifies font
    labels: [300, 436, 573, 710,850],  // Print labels at these values
    fractionDigits: 0  // Optional: Numerical precision. 0=round off.
  },
  staticZones: [
   {strokeStyle: "#00FF00", min: 300, max: 436},
   {strokeStyle: "#0000FF", min: 437, max: 573},
   {strokeStyle: "#FFFF00", min: 574, max: 710},
   {strokeStyle: "#FF0000", min: 711, max: 850},
  ],
  limitMax: false,
  limitMin: false,
  strokeColor: '#E0E0E0',
    generateGradient: false,
  highDpiSupport: true
  };
selectGauge3.minValue = 300;
selectGauge3.maxValue = 850;
selectGauge3.setOptions(opts);
selectGauge3.set(310);
```

I am using above code ..

Comment: I dont have any knowledge about gauge, so i only add a comment: try to define the line-height (font: 20px/0px sans-seif).